# Export CSV file column to other CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a .CSV file containing serial numbers with warranty start and end dates.
Case in point:

```
ServiceTag | StarDate         | EndDate
2PONKFL    | 2017-09-13 02:00 | 2018-09-14 02:00
2PONKFL    | 2017-09-13 02:00 | 2018-09-14 02:00
2PONKFL    | 2017-09-13 02:00 | 2023-09-14 02:00
9LPYHUJ    | 2012-05-09 02:00 | 2013-05-09 02:00
9LPYHUJ    | 2012-05-09 02:00 | 2015-05-09 02:00
9LPYHUJ    | 2012-05-09 02:00 | 2018-05-09 02:00
9LPYHUJ    | 2012-05-09 02:00 | 2020-05-09 02:00
```

I would like to retrieve a serial number with the most recent date as EndDate and do this for each service number and export it to another .CSV file.

The goal is to have another .CSV file with the serial number + the most recent date for each serial number. I hope I've been clear enough on the subject.

I'm not very good at Powershell programming, I still managed to export the data from my CSV to another CSV but not by doing a "Selection".

Comment: Could you use python? this looks like an easy task on pandas lib

Comment: I would have liked to do this in powershell, however if it would be easier for you and you have an idea don't hesitate to put something on. 
In summary for each serial number I would like to have the most recent warranty end date. Thank you Ivan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With PowerShell, this is not that hard to do.
Since the dates are all in sortable format (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm), you don't even have to parse these strings into real datetime objects:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME OF THE CSV' -Delimiter '|'
$result = $csv | Group-Object ServiceTag | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Group | Sort-Object -Property EndDate | Select-Object -Last 1
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to new CSV
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME OF THE NEW CSV' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Update**

It seems your CSV file has extraneus spaces around the headers and fields which makes it more difficult to use.

To overcome that you could replace the top line

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME OF THE CSV' -Delimiter '|'
```

with

```
$csv = ((Get-Content -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME OF THE CSV') -replace '\s+\|\s+', '|').Trim() | 
         ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter '|'
```

**NOTE**

Always make sure you know what the delimiter character actually is. Open the CSV file in Notepad first to check this.

Instead of te above you can make it more versatile using:

```
[char]$delimiter = ';'   # enter the delimiter character here
$csv = ((Get-Content -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME OF THE CSV') -replace "\s+\$delimiter\s+", $delimiter).Trim() | 
         ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter $delimiter
```

If I were you, I'd save this cleaned-up content as new, proper CSV file using

```
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'PATH AND FILENAME OF THE CSV' -Delimiter '|' -NoTypeInformation
```

<sup>If the delimiter in the CSV is not the pipe symbol `|`, then change this in the code</sup>

Comment: It's a good thing there are people like you who are familiar with powershell. 
It works but it only shows me the serial number, 9LPYHUJ but not 2PONKFL. However there is well the loop ForEach-object I do not understand why it does not scan the file...

Comment: @Smarty13 Check the input CSV file. If there are spaces around the headers you should either remove them (recommended), or add them to the code as in `Group-Object 'ServiceTag '`

Comment: @Smarty13 If I test it, it returns the exact two lines you are after. That is why I asked to check the CSV file. In your question, you only show an edited output, not the real thing. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59983921/edit) the question and put the actual csv contents in there please?

Comment: I tried to make some changes to your script and it worked. I do have a serial number with the most recent warranty expiration date. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Smarty13 You're welcome! Thanks for the nice feedback.

Comment: I have another small question related to the same example. 

In my .csv I have the headings: Service Tag, Start Date, End Date between the two there is a space like this is when I run the script it doesn't work anymore... and when I remove the space between ServiceTag , StartDate , EndDate it works again... Theo do you have an idea how to make the script work even if there is a space in the CSV fields?

Comment: @Smarty13 See the update of my answer. This will get rid of the excess whitespace characters in the file.

Comment: I tried and I have the same problem. Did you try it on your own? If it worked, I'm going to find out... .
I will explain it again and try to be as clear as possible:  
In my CSV the fields are like this: Service Tag;Start Date;End Date and at each header there's a space, that makes the program crash. The goal would be to remove the space between: Service Tag;Start Date;End Date for the program to work. 
I hope I was clearer in the explanations.

Comment: @Smarty13 I have added an extra Note to the answer. Please check what delimiter character is actually used in the file (open in Notepad and check). P.S. nothing _crashes_, but using the wrong delimiter character will simply not make it do what you want)

Comment: I just found the problem... your old modification worked and so did the new one! The problem came from : 
Group-Object ServiceTag & Sort-Object -Property EndDate I forgot to make this change by putting a space and quotes. Thank you very much again

Comment: Hello Theo, I created the same .csv with 15 serial numbers and I see that there is half where it recovers the highest date of end of guarantee and the other half where it does not recover the highest date.  

Would it be possible to use a script with the command arr.max(..) for the End Date? or another way... thank you for everything.

Comment: @Smarty13 It all depends on the CSV you are loading. In the example all dates are in sortable format (i.e. all date and time parts go from largest to smallest 'unit'). If your new CSV does not use that same format in the date columns, things go wrong of course. Please make sure you create proper CSV files (without spaces surrounding the headers and values) and also have the fields use the exact same format.

Comment: I put a screen capture in your "note" field.

Comment: @Smarty13 As I said.. This line ` 2YGMV84;04/02/2014 02:00:00;04/03/2015 01:59` uses a different format for the end date than all the rest. It is missing the hours part on the time. So again, please make sure you are working with proper CSV. Also, the date format in your comment is completely different from the one you posted in the question. There it uses `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` where in your comment it suddenly changed to `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss` which is **NO LONGER** a sortable date format. The code is using the format as posted originally, not what you make of it now.

Comment: @Smarty13 When you create your CSV, you need to make sure the dates in it are ALL written out the same way if you later want to do something with those dates. Now, you seem to not care about how dates are formatted (with complete time parts or without, using dashes or slashes or everything mixed together) which will make it near impossible to parse them out in order to do a sort. The date format you used in the question was perfect for sorting. If that was not at all like the stuff you show now, the question was wrong I'm afraid..

Comment: Okay, I think I know what you meant. It seems to be working out in the end. Thank you, Theo.